# numpy ndarray subclass: ufunc don't return scalar type

Tags: python, numpy, subclass, scalar, multidimensional-array

For `numpy.ndarray` subclass, ufunc outputs have the same type. This is good in general but I would like for ufunc with scalar output to return scalar type (such as `numpy.float64`).

Example:

```
import numpy as np

class MyArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, array):
        obj = np.asarray(array).view(cls)
        return obj

a = MyArray(np.arange(5))
a*2
# MyArray([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])  => same class as original (i.e. MyArray), ok

a.sum()
# MyArray(10)               => same as original, but here I'd expect np.int64

type(2*a) is type(a.sum())
# True                    
b = a.view(np.ndarray)
type(2*b) is type(b.sum())    
# False
```

For standard numpy array, scalar output have scalar type. So how to have the same behavior for my subclass?

I'm using Python 2.7.3 with numpy 1.6.2 on an OSX 10.6

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: do you want to have e.g. `sum()` to always return a `float64`, regardless whether `a` is an integer or floating point array?

Comment: No, I would like it to return the same as `a.view(np.ndarray).sum()`: to have the same behaviors than for traditional array.

Comment: Ok, that's odd then, because when I run your code, `a.sum()` is `np.int64` for me. Python 2.7.5 + NumPy 1.7.0, as well as Python 3.3.2 + Numpy 1.8.0-dev.

Comment: Note: you might be confusing `a.sum().dtype` and `type(a.sum())`.

Comment: My results match OP's, not @Evert's.  Numpy `1.7.1`, Python `2.7.5`.  It's interesting that the output is squeezed, as in it has shape `()` not `(1,)`, but it isn't cast to a scalar.  So it's not effected by the fact that `np.sum()` ignores the `keepdims` parameter if the type is not `ndarray`.

Comment: @Evert/@askewchan: strange... I added my spec in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override `__array_wrap__` in your ndarray subclass with a function that looks like this:

```
def __array_wrap__(self, obj):
    if obj.shape == ():
        return obj[()]    # if ufunc output is scalar, return it
    else:
        return np.ndarray.__array_wrap__(self, obj)
```

`__array_wrap__` is called after ufuncs to do cleanup work.  In the default implementation special cases exact ndarrays (but not subclasses) to convert zero-rank arrays to scalars.  At least this is true for some versions of numpy.