# numpy.nanmean() on a subclass of numpy.ndarray returns unexpected type

Tags: numpy

starting from a popular example

```
import numpy as np

class TestArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(subtype, shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0,
          strides=None, order=None):
        obj = np.ndarray.__new__(subtype, shape, dtype, buffer, offset, strides,
                         order)

        return obj

obj = TestArray(shape=(3,))
obj[:] = [1, 2, 3]
print type(np.nanmean(obj))
print type(np.nanmean(numpy.array(obj)))
```

gives the output

```
<class '__main__.TestArray'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

I'd rather like numpy.nanmean(obj) to return also a numpy.float64.

Now obviously I can cast to numpy.array, but I don't want to do this.

What do I need to modify in the class definition such that numpy.nanmean() (and probably others) return always the same type as if called with a numpy.ndarray directly?

Comment: did you read the docs? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html

Comment: thanks / yes I read the docs but it seems that I'm to stupid to understand it ;-(

Comment: it seems that

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223926/numpy-ndarray-subclass-ufunc-dont-return-scalar-type

answers my question.